# knockout - how to get a button's Text value?

Tags: javascript, button, text, knockout.js

I am seeing if I can avoid writing separate functions to handle separate button clicks. If I can read the Text value of the button that was clicked, then I can use one function called "showName" and use a switch statement to handle each respective button click.

Is this possible?

```
<body>
    <button data-bind="click: showName">Show Name</button>
    <button data-bind="click: showName">Show Lists</button>
</body>
```

I tried various methods below. I want to get the value "Show Name" if the first button is clicked. But none of these are working.

```
function TutorialsViewModel(){
    this.showName = function(e){           
        console.log(e);
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(e.target.value);
    };   
}

ko.applyBindings(new TutorialsViewModel());
```

Comment: Did you try setting `id` attributes to your `<button>` tags?

Comment: I was seeing if I could avoid id tags as well. To make the elements as generic as possible. Per your answer below, the fix is to expand my function parameters to be (data, e). Although it works without using id, it is, as you suggest, better to use unique id attributes. This way, I can change the button text later on without having to modify the corresponding innerText in the JS code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `e.target.value` you need to use `e.target.innerText`.

**Here is a working Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/e8JPT/315/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <button id="btn1" data-bind="click: log">Show Name</button>
    <button id="btn2" data-bind="click: log">Show Lists</button>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
var TutorialsViewModel=function(){
    this.log = function(data, event){           

        alert("You clicked on : " +event.target.innerText);
    };   
}

ko.applyBindings(new TutorialsViewModel());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. My javascript function needed 2 parameters (data, event). I was only supplying 1 parameter (e). I was pretty sure I was doing it correct conceptually. Just had a miss on syntax. Much appreciated !

Comment: I left out that I had also tried e.target.innerHTML. Once I fixed the parameters, this works as well. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Using stackoverflow as example, you can use the function `getElementsByName` `getElementsByClassName`or `getElementsById` to retrieve any element from a page, and have access to all of it's properties. `name`, `value`, `innerHTML` , etc ...

Example from StackOverflow from any browser's console (F12 to open):

```
var button = document.getElementById("submit-button"); 
//this only works if the button has id="submit-button"
button.value;
// output : "Text in button"
```